# mostrar mediante un texto en que ciudad estoy angular js

Tags: angularjs, html5, ionic, geolocalización

Estoy realizando una app en ionic en donde quiero mostrarle al usuario en que ciudad está. Con este código lo ubico pero necesito mostrarle algo por ejemplo:

> Estás en Barranquilla/Cartagena o algo así

**Controlador:**

```
.controller('CtrlUbi', function($scope) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.position = position; //Obtenemos info de la localizaicon
        console.log(position.coords.latitude);
        console.log(position.coords.longitude);
        console.log(position)
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Por favor, en tu próxima pregunta trata de identar y formatear bien el código. Ya he editado tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar Google Maps para lograr tu cometido.

**Requisitos**

- [obtén tu llave](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) de Google Maps.
- HTTPS

Agregas Google Maps a tu documento:

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=TU_LLAVE"></script>
```

**NOTA:** Donde dice `TU_LLAVE` obviamente va tu llave de Google Maps.

Luego creas un `Geocoder` para obtener tu localización y obtienes las llaves `locality` de cada resultado (te vienen varios).

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
  const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  let location;

  location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
  geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': location }, (results, status) => {
    processLocation(results);
  });
});

function processLocation(location) {
  if (location[1]) {
    for (var i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
      if (location[i].types[0] === "locality") {
        let city = location[i].address_components[0].short_name;
        let state = location[i].address_components[2].short_name;
        let country = location[i].address_components[3].long_name;

        console.log(city, state, country);
      }
    }
  }
}
```